# 45GB Photoshop psb file will not open in Photoshop on new 2019 MacBook Pro running Mojave

Tags: macbook, adobe-photoshop, macos-mojave

I have a 45GB multi-layer/multi-channel Photoshop psb file that I have been working on for the past few months. I had been editing it in Photoshop 2018 (v19.1) on a mid-2014 MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.13.6.

I recently upgraded to a 2019 MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.6.

File would open on previous laptop fine, it just took 5+ minutes.
On the new laptop, it just won't open at all. It stops after writing around 22 GB and becomes unresponsive for hours.

### Previous Macbook Pro/Photoshop (file opens):

- Hardware: Macbook Pro 15-inch Mid 2014
- OS: High Sierra (10.13.6)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
- Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- Software: Photoshop CC 2018 19.1.0

### New MacBook Pro/Photoshop (file does not open):

- Hardware: Macbook Pro 15-inch 2019
- OS: Mojave (10.14.6)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Graphics:

  - Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB
  - Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- Software: Photoshop CC 2019 20.0.6

### Attempts with the previous Macbook Pro and Photoshop to make compatible with the new laptop:

- Saving with compression off,
- Saving without a color profile
- Saving in a number of locations
- Saving on an external drive
- Turning off graphics hardware acceleration
- Saving and opening with multiple versions of Photoshop 2017, 2018, and 2019
- Opens psb's 15GB or less just fine
- Change scratch disk allocation to only the main drive, then back to an external disk
- Changed Photoshop RAM allocation to 50% then back to 90%
- Turn on Accessibilty for Photoshop in System Preferences

Comment: Your hardware specifications for both devices are identical which doesn’t make since, you indicated the second device is a 2019 MacBook.  Edit your question and clarify the details.  You need to specify what processor you have.  Saying you have an i7 doesn’t tell us which processor you actually have.

Comment: @Ramhound Ack! Sorry. Updated second device details.

Comment: @Ramhound As far as the processor details, I'm not sure what to include besides "2.3 GHz Intel Core i9" for example.

Comment: There are 9 Generations of Intel Core products.  Which means there are at least 75 i7s on the market (2014 reduces that to about 40).  Provide the product page on Intels website for your processor.  Storage space is important when dealing with Photoshop since you can define swap space (since a 40 GB file can’t fit into memory).  Have you enabled hardware acceleration on the new machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Got it... updated. Ran `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` in command-line

Comment: @Ramhound New laptop has 150GB of free space, but not sure if that's what you meant re: swap space. Photoshop GPU acceleration was enabled, disabled, then re-enabled on different attempts. OS preferences are set to always use high performance graphics.

Comment: It’s called a [scratch disk](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-photoshop-cc-performance.html) would be helpful if you provided the scratch disk configuration for both machines

Comment: @Ramhound [Performance](https://imgur.com/a/FjJTGAx) [Scratch Disk](https://imgur.com/a/45Q424s) from new machine.

Comment: @Ramhound [Performance](https://imgur.com/a/1wc8yxx) [Scratch Disk](https://imgur.com/a/Ohzk1zr) from old machine

Comment: You have numerous disks enabled as a scratch disk on the new machine but only the single disk on the old. Likewise, you have OpenGL disabled on the old machine (including the native operating system GPU acceleration) on the old machine.

Comment: How much RAM on the two systems?  Even if you can load that file, I suspect working on it  would be slow as molasses unless the Macbook has some serious resources.  To paraphrase Jaws, "you may need a bigger boat."

Comment: Some tests - prefs>performance, set memory to 50% of your total, Switch off 'Use Graphics processor'. Then remove the 2 external drives from scratch disk usage. Relaunch. [I'd also like to know what RAM both machines have.]

Comment: @Ramhound I tried aligning those settings of the new laptop with the settings of the old... still no luck.

Comment: @fixer1234 16GB RAM of both machines. This seemed to be enough resources on the old machine as I was able to edit the file without the laptop slowing down.

Comment: @Tetsujin 16GB RAM on both machines... I tried adjusting the settings you mentioned, but still no luck. When I look at the activity monitor each time I try to open the file, the Photoshop process always shows that it writes the first 22GB to disk, then just hangs.

Comment: Hmm… I'm stuck, sorry. I don't have anything like that size I can test here either, my biggest files are only a couple of GB. I'd be tempted to flag this for migration to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com & see if anyone there has any better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* have something to do with the need to allocate more contiguous scratch disk space. I had ~150gb SSD space as my primary scratch disk. When I used my external 8TB drive as my sole scratch disk holder, it took 20 minutes, but it eventually opened.